# m3u8 not loading in video tag

Tags: html, video, http-live-streaming

I am trying to load this in a video tag but it is not loading. If I go to the link directly on my iPhone or android phone it will play without problems.

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://vod.ak.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/AUTH_system/vods_2f44/asiagodtonegg3be0_17169379616_331512496/high/highlight-22030149-muted-Y56G7SNUCG.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: m3u8 is NOT a video file. it's a file which tells the player where the video file really is. so saying it's video/mp4 is outright wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct type is `application/x-mpegURL` or `vnd.apple.mpegURL`

Comment: I tried this but it don't work. `<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://vod.ak.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/AUTH_system/vods_4b2f/troflecopter_17257271344_334297630/medium/highlight-22615978-muted-CUWR10CWO8.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>` on js fiddler too. And even on [http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video](w3schools examples)

Comment: It works on all devices that support HLS natively, like Android 4.x+ iOS or Safari 6+ on desktops. Note it doesn't have autoplay.

Comment: oh that would explain it. Thanks. I was testing it on chrome desktop version.

Comment: for Chrome on desktop you need a player with Flash fallback, like https://github.com/clappr/clappr

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for following up with this.